# Creating a Loop to pass an array of variables in oracle SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

So this does not work, looks like you can only pass a counter this way like 1...10:

```
BEGIN
For var_code in (01,10,11,B3,B4,B6,B7)
LOOP
    IF HOLD.HOLD_var_code IS NOT NULL THEN

                         DELETE FROM SATURN.SPRHOLD
                              WHERE SPRHOLD_PIDM = HOLD.PIDM
                                AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = 'var_code';
                     END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

So I tried this, which i found the on another post. but i dont know how to pass the var to attach to a name like in HOLD.HOLD_i:

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('01','10','11','B3','B4','B6','B7'))) 
LOOP
IF HOLD.HOLD_i.column_value IS NOT NULL THEN
                         DELETE FROM SATURN.SPRHOLD
                              WHERE SPRHOLD_PIDM = HOLD.PIDM
                                AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = 'i.column_value';
                     END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

but the HOLD.HOLD_i.column_value is not working, i tried HOLD_'i.column_value' and HOLD_||i.column_value to no avail. any suggestions.

sorry i don't have the error list. i'm not at my workstation where i can run the code.

Update: the person who needed this changed the request, so I no longer need to do this anymore.... (facepalm)

Comment: What is `HOLD`? That doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: @AlexPoole my bad, this section is from a much larger package. HOLD.HOLD_XX is the name of the column where i need to know if a value exist or not. so if I was just removing one hold code. i twould be: If HOLD.HOLD_01  is not null then...... SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = '01';

Comment: You end your question with "so I no longer need to do this anymore.... (facepalm)" Then please delete the question; do not have community members attempting to provide an answer for something you no longer want.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is record with field `column_value`, so use

```sql
IF i.column_value IS NOT NULL THEN...
```

Of course if you alias column_value - `SELECT column_value as foo FROM table...`, then use `i.foo`.

Comment: the problem is there are two different places I need to put the numeric value in. one is attached to a column name and the other is by itself. So the IF statement needs to be: IF HOLD.HOLD_01 is not null (but replace that 01 with the each in the list) and then the delete statement would be the 01 by itself like sprhold_hold_code = '01'

Comment: basically for each loop i need 2 pass two variables: "hold.hold_01,01", (hold.hold_10,10) if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have a hardcoded list; you don't need to run multiple SQL statements in a loop and try to dynamically get values from the `HOLD` object (it is undocumented in your question so we do not know if it is a package or cursor) and can just use a single statement with multiple `OR` expressions to avoid having to use dynamic SQL:

```sql
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM SATURN.SPRHOLD
  WHERE  SPRHOLD_PIDM = HOLD.PIDM
  AND    (  ( HOLD.HOLD_01 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = '01' )
         OR ( HOLD.HOLD_10 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = '10' )
         OR ( HOLD.HOLD_11 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = '11' )
         OR ( HOLD.HOLD_B3 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = 'B3' )
         OR ( HOLD.HOLD_B4 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = 'B4' )
         OR ( HOLD.HOLD_B5 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = 'B5' )
         OR ( HOLD.HOLD_B6 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = 'B6' )
         OR ( HOLD.HOLD_B7 IS NOT NULL AND SPRHOLD_HLDD_CODE = 'B7' )
         );
END;
```

Comment: than you for the response, my goal was/is trying to avoid writing out each one in an or statement or separate queries, which is why i was trying the loop. sorry i did not explain the problem better. Would this delete mutiple entries per a person? meaning if the record had a value in hold_01 and hold_10, would it delete both entries out of the sprhold table?

Comment: @moore1emu Try it and see. Without your table structure and sample data to test it on it is difficult to say for certain but I would expect that it would delete both entries. However, using a loop and running 10 SQL statements is less efficient that just using 1 SQL statement and trying to use dynamic SQL is even less efficient; so unless you need to pass a dynamic list of values (or there are thousands of values), I would say to hardcode the values into a single SQL statement.